# CSV file columns overlapping

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a CSV file with multiple columns, however as well as the comma's there are astrix (*) separating the data. When I open the file in excel some of the columns merge into others if there is a blank field, creating a skew. I have tried to open in notebook and use * as the delimiter but still get the same results. I have also removed all comma's but again I am still getting the same problem. Is there any features I can use the will recognise a blank field and show it? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your CSV file, as well as how it renders in Excel?

Comment: usually, if you choose a .csv through the file -> open dialogue (as opposed to opening it from explorer), excel will start the "text import wizard" which lets you choose how to treat the delimiters, spaces, etc. This should enable ypu to order your data in a sensible way, if your .csv file has a coherent logical structure